# RemObjects PascalScript How to get the value of the variable after compilation?

Tags: pascalscript, remobjects

RemObjects PascalScript.
How to get the value of the variable after compilation?

```
var a,b,c: integer;
begin
a := 5;
b := 6;
c := a+b;
end;
```

cc := IntTostr(????c????);

Comment: You want to get Value of C in your main program, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

You can register a function with

```
Sender.AddDelphiFunction('procedure MyOwnFunction(Data: string)');
```

and

```
Exec := TPSExec.Create;  // Create an instance of the executer.
Exec.RegisterDelphiFunction(@MyOwnFunction, 'MYOWNFUNCTION', cdRegister);
```

and then call it from within your script.

Alternatively, you can define your script as a `function` and set the `Result`. Then you can retrieve it with

```
TestFunc := TTestFunction(Exec.GetProcAsMethodN('Test'));
```

Both methods are demonstrated in [this example](https://github.com/remobjects/pascalscript/blob/master/Samples/Console/sample8.dpr):

```
program sample8;

uses
  uPSCompiler,
  uPSRuntime,
  uPSUtils,

  Dialogs;

procedure MyOwnFunction(const Data: string);
begin
  // Do something with Data
  ShowMessage(Data);
end;

{$IFDEF UNICODE}
function ScriptOnExportCheck(Sender: TPSPascalCompiler; Proc: TPSInternalProcedure; const ProcDecl: AnsiString): Boolean;
{$ELSE}
function ScriptOnExportCheck(Sender: TPSPascalCompiler; Proc: TPSInternalProcedure; const ProcDecl: string): Boolean;
{$ENDIF}
{
  The OnExportCheck callback function is called for each function in the script
  (Also for the main proc, with '!MAIN' as a Proc^.Name). ProcDecl contains the
  result type and parameter types of a function using this format:
  ProcDecl: ResultType + ' ' + Parameter1 + ' ' + Parameter2 + ' '+Parameter3 + .....
  Parameter: ParameterType+TypeName
  ParameterType is @ for a normal parameter and ! for a var parameter.
  A result type of 0 means no result.
}
begin
  if Proc.Name = 'TEST' then // Check if the proc is the Test proc we want.
  begin
    if not ExportCheck(Sender, Proc, {$IFDEF UNICODE}[btUnicodeString, btUnicodeString]{$ELSE}[btString, btString]{$ENDIF}, [pmIn]) then // Check if the proc has the correct params.
    begin
      { Something is wrong, so cause an error. }
      Sender.MakeError('', ecTypeMismatch, '');
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
    Result := True;
  end else Result := True;
end;

{$IFDEF UNICODE}
function ScriptOnUses(Sender: TPSPascalCompiler; const Name: AnsiString): Boolean;
{$ELSE}
function ScriptOnUses(Sender: TPSPascalCompiler; const Name: string): Boolean;
{$ENDIF}
{ the OnUses callback function is called for each "uses" in the script.
  It's always called with the parameter 'SYSTEM' at the top of the script.
  For example: uses ii1, ii2;
  This will call this function 3 times. First with 'SYSTEM' then 'II1' and then 'II2'.
}
begin
  if Name = 'SYSTEM' then
  begin

    Sender.AddDelphiFunction('procedure MyOwnFunction(Data: string)');
    { This will register the function to the script engine. Now it can be used from within the script. }


    Result := True;
  end else
    Result := False;
end;

type
  TTestFunction = function (const s: string): string of object;
  // Header of the test function, added of object. 

procedure ExecuteScript(const Script: string);
var
  Compiler: TPSPascalCompiler;
  { TPSPascalCompiler is the compiler part of the scriptengine. This will
    translate a Pascal script into a compiled form the executer understands. }
  Exec: TPSExec;
   { TPSExec is the executer part of the scriptengine. It uses the output of
    the compiler to run a script. }
  {$IFDEF UNICODE}Data: AnsiString;{$ELSE}Data: string;{$ENDIF}

  TestFunc: TTestFunction;
begin
  Compiler := TPSPascalCompiler.Create; // create an instance of the compiler.
  Compiler.OnUses := ScriptOnUses; // assign the OnUses event.

  Compiler.OnExportCheck := ScriptOnExportCheck; // Assign the onExportCheck event.

  Compiler.AllowNoBegin := True;
  Compiler.AllowNoEnd := True; // AllowNoBegin and AllowNoEnd allows it that begin and end are not required in a script. 

  if not Compiler.Compile(Script) then  // Compile the Pascal script into bytecode.
  begin
    Compiler.Free;
     // You could raise an exception here.
    Exit;
  end;

  Compiler.GetOutput(Data); // Save the output of the compiler in the string Data.
  Compiler.Free; // After compiling the script, there is no need for the compiler anymore.

  Exec := TPSExec.Create;  // Create an instance of the executer.

  Exec.RegisterDelphiFunction(@MyOwnFunction, 'MYOWNFUNCTION', cdRegister);

  if not Exec.LoadData(Data) then // Load the data from the Data string.
  begin
    { For some reason the script could not be loaded. This is usually the case when a 
      library that has been used at compile time isn't registered at runtime. }
    Exec.Free;
     // You could raise an exception here.
    Exit;
  end;

  TestFunc := TTestFunction(Exec.GetProcAsMethodN('Test'));
  if @TestFunc <> nil then
    ShowMessage('Result from TestFunc(''test indata''): '+TestFunc('test indata'));

  Exec.Free; // Free the executer.
end;



const
  Script = 'function test(s: string): string; begin MyOwnFunction(''Test Called with param: ''+s); Result := ''Test Result: ''+s; end;';

begin
  ExecuteScript(Script);
end.
```